# Streamlit is alphabetising the X axis of line_chart

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

Here is my code:

```
    temps = {'Day': ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
         'Temp' : [20, 17, 28, 31, 25, 22, 24]}

df = pd.DataFrame(temps)
st.dataframe(df)
st.line_chart(df.set_index('Day'))
```

When I load the streamlit page, the Temp data displays correctly but the Day data gets alphabatised and does not plot mon - sun but displays the days of the week in alphabetical order. Anyone know a way around this?

Thanks!

J

Comment: maybe converting `Day` into category helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`altair.Chart`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html) (*that is run under the hood*) sort both axes by default (*see [GH1245](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1245)*).

As a workaround (while running [`streamlit==1.26.0`](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/releases/tag/1.26.0)), you can add `sort=None` in  `~\venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\arrow_altair.py` :

```
    return alt.X(
        x_field,
        title=x_title,
        type=_get_x_encoding_type(df, chart_type, x_column),
        scale=_get_scale(df, x_column),
        axis=_get_axis_config(df, x_column, grid=False),
        sort=None, # <-- added line (1079)
    )
```

Output (*in Streamlit*) :

[image]

Comment: **NB** : You might want to make a [*feature request*](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%3Aenhancement&projects=&template=feature_request.yml) to add a `sort` parameter in [`line_chart`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.line_chart).